Automate Launch of Several Android Applications
Recently, I learned about Android Automatization (e.g., with Tasker, LLamaLab, and MacroDroid). However, several hours of Googling have not led to the desired automatization routine. Perhaps somebody has already observed a similar problem or challenge and has already found a solution.
The configuration: Lineage OS 21, Pixel 4a, Not Rooted
The desired automated blocks are(without explaining why):

Download the Lineage OS update if it is available and install it. The problem with this step is that it requires a reboot.
Open the app store and update the apps and app store. Wait for completion, and close the app store. Note that I have several different app stores for different apps.
Open the antivirus, update the databases, scan everything, wait for completion, and close the antivirus.
Open Termux, update packages, synchronize some files with git, wait for completion, and close Termux.
Copy some files to Google Drive, wait for completion, and close Google Drive.

These steps are repeated weekly or monthly, so automating them would make things easier for me. If you have ideas on some particular steps but not for all, your response is appreciated regardless. Whether the approach requires root or not is important.

Your question is a bit too general, especially the "app stores" part and the "antivirus" part can not be answered without specifying the exact stores/antivirus app you use.

Possibly related: How to automate UI of a 3rd party applications?.
